# Путь к папке c js скриптами!

Tags: javascript, минификация

Мне потребовалось сделать минификацию всех js файлов в папке на сервере. Нашёл скрипт, который эту функцию выполняет. Не очень понимаю как правильно путь указать в следующей строке - const files = globSync(`${process.env.TERSER_DIST_PATH || './dist'}/*.js`) . Это я так понимаю - где лежат все файлы js!

Если у меня лежат файлы js по следующему пути /bonus/js/ - то как правильно указать?